# How to uniquely identify remote request host

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http

I'm building an API with Rails that is going to receive HTTP requests from other sites.

Every time a new request is issued, I need to know in my app if this site has already sent this request. So, I'm wondering if there is a way to uniquely identify the site sending the request. I'm thinking of using `request.remote_ip` however if the site is on a shared hosting, it would share the same IP address with other sites.
Is there any other way to identify the remote origin?

Comment: If there's no registration or authentication for the API consumers, there's only so much you can do.  The IP address is all you really have.

Comment: There is a registration and token based authentication, however we are going to provide a free trial upon registration, so I want to make sure that one site can have only one free trial. Otherwise, they can keep on creating new accounts and have unlimited trials.

Answer (score 0):

If the request is issued from an API client then the *IP* is all you have that you can (somewhat) rely on.
And as you mentioned this is not really unique (proxy, shared hosting, ...).